# Any vector bundle can be twisted to have sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be an integral scheme proper over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $V$ be a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of positive finite rank. Does there necessarily exist a locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-module of rank 1 $L$ such that $L\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} V$ has non-zero global sections? If not, what additional hypotheses save the day (e.g. normality, factoriality etc.).

I think this should be true for line bundles (one can take the dual line bundle and the tensor product will be the structure sheaf).

Comment: If $X$ is projective, you can take $L$ to be a sufficiently ample line bundle.

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users/